# How to prevent a logged in user from posting a post using anothers user name in django rest framework

Tags: python, django

In my Django rest framework project I want to make sure that for example if testuser1 is logged in when posting a post cannot on the author part chose testuser2 and post the post with the author being testuser2. How I can I make sure only the logged in user creates a post?

my models.py

```
from turtle import title
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.utils import timezone

class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    body = models.TextField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

my views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from rest_framework import generics, permissions
from .models import Post
from .serializers import PostSerializer
from .permissions import IsAuthorOrReadOnly

class PostList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    #permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)
    queryset = Post.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PostSerializer


class PostDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthorOrReadOnly,)
    queryset = Post.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PostSerializer
```

my serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Post

class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        fields = ('id', 'author', 'title', 'body', 'created_at',)
        model = Post
```

my permissions.py

```
from re import T
from tkinter.tix import Tree
from rest_framework import permissions

class IsAuthorOrReadOnly(permissions.BasePermission):
    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        # Read-only permissions are allowed for any request
        if request.method in permissions.SAFE_METHODS:
            return True

        # Write permissions are only allowed to the author of a post
        return obj.author == request.user
```

Comment: What error are you encountering?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Another user, for example when testuser1 is logged in has the ability to create a post and choose the author as testuser2 . This is what I want to prevent. Only the logged in user when posting a post  can chose their author name only on author.

Answer (score 0):

use perform_create worked for me

```
 def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(author = self.request.user)
```

Comment: Also author field should be read_only in serializer because you always want to set author_field in serializer.